# Change `uri` of unfiltered.request.HttpRequest?

Tags: scala, unfiltered

Given an `unfiltered` [HttpRequest](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/ws/unfiltered/unfiltered-all_2.12/0.9.1/unfiltered-all_2.12-0.9.1-javadoc.jar/!/unfiltered/request/HttpRequest.html), how can I modify the `uri`?

Example:

val req: unfiltered.request.HttpRequest[javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] = ???

How can I produce a new `unfiltered.request.HttpRequest[javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]` with its `uri` changed?

Comment: Didn't look much but `abstract class HttpRequest[+T]` suggests you might need the implementations rather than the base class.

Comment: Your solution may be here https://github.com/unfiltered/unfiltered/blob/18b8ee2e5c23d879d2bb37a58ba4cd43192e70e6/library/src/main/scala/request/delegating.scala